# Which tablet with a lot of sensors (proximity, pressure,...)?

Tags: android, tablet

I have to buy a tablet for a research project. During the project I have to collect sensor and user inputs of the tablet (The goal is to predict the attention level of the user with machine learning). I'm thinking about the following sensors / specifications the tablet should have:

- Proximity sensor (proximity of face to device)
- Acceleration
- Gyroscope
- Pressure sensor (touchscreen pressure)
- Touchscreen input (where touched, trace,...)
- GPS
- Audio / Video (front cam)
- Sim card slot / WLAN

If there are more sensor which I'm currently not aware of, feel free to mention them.

Of course the OS (e.g. Android) has to provide facility to read out the corresponding values. I think the Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 fulfills all requirements, except the pressure sensor. I'm not aware of an Android device which has a pressure sensor built in. I know that new Apple smartphone have a pressure sensor but I don't know if Apple tablets have a pressure sensor as well.

Which device would you recommend fulfilling the above requirements (and having perhaps additional sensors)? May it be Android or iOS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article linked below mentions that pressure sensitivity has been implemented in Android since API Level 5.

I would see no reason why the S2 wouldn't have these features.

http://pocketnow.com/2015/09/07/force-touch-android-has-had-that-for-years

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not find any information about a pressure sensor in the S2. Is this pressure sensing only a derived quantity from the area of the fingerprint or a real pressure sensor (like apple smartphones have)?

Comment: I wouldn't know sorry, maybe someone else can help?